# Determining which encryption algorithm to use

Tags: algorithm-design

I'm a traditional software engineer.  Recently, due to the nature of a current project, I have been exposed to many cryptographic libraries--there are so many encryption algorithms!

How do you choose the right algorithm for your application? What advantages/disadvantages do different types of algorithms bring with them?. Is there one algorithm that could be seen as the "standard" that should always be used?

Comment: You first create a use case and threat factors on that use case. Then you start to chose solutions to make sure that the threat factors are not significant anymore (the total of which is the threat model). These solutions may or may not include cryptography. The cryptography that *is* used should be molded within well described protocols. Finally, the protocols need to use secure algorithms that fit the protocol. What kind of algorithm is to be used should be the *final* decision to be made. Any requirement that starts with: "you have to use AES" might as well be thrown in the bin right away.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I seem to remember recently posting something along the lines of your last sentence (seems to have disappeared though).  The reason I did that was to provide a counter context to those (you know who) that seem to forcefully insist that all encryption is now done only as AES-GCM with 256 bit keys. That seemed entirely appropriate for a 'standard encryption' question.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks for the comment, I liked especially the last sentence.

Comment: Don't take it separately from the context. There is nothing wrong with AES - if well implemented and applied - and it is used for many protocols. However, it forces people to use a bottom-up approach when designing a secure system, and that's not the right direction in the fast majority of cases (sometimes you have this security chip that just supports 3DES and AES, and yeah...use AES is not that bad a requirement in that particular case).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes that "you have to use AES" requirement might be just fine if you are an employee or contractor for the US government

Comment: Depends if confidentiality is what you are after. Even then: work top to bottom, and use AES if a (block) cipher is required.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I was thinking more for FIPS compliance, as AES is the only FIPS block cipher right now (I think)